# Information required about cookies in php

Tags: php, session, cookies

I want to enable the cookies on my site. For this I used the following code:

```
$cookie_name = 'testing_cookie';
$cookie_value = 'test_cookie_set_with_php';
($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (86400 * 30), '/'); // 86400 = 1 day
```

I am not sure what to put in "cookie_name", "cookie_value", what is this for.

Second I want to know the user preference of the pages, where he/she visits on the site. How can I get the reports.

Third I saw a message on Cookies enabled site, which asked to ok the terms that they are using cookies on their site. How can I do it?

Comment: If you don't understand what to use for `cookie_name` and `cookie_value`, do you actually know what cookies are?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your second requirement (user preference)?

Comment: @MarkBaker to identify the user in the specified time period which we mentioned.

Comment: @morido I meant like I want to know what user do on my site, from where  I can get the reports.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll go through your individual subquestions one by one:

1. Cookies are essentially a structure consisting of a *name* (to differentiate them), a *value* (your actual payload) and possibly a few other fields. See the PHP docs of [`setcookie()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) for a more in-depth explanation.
2. If you are referring to *site analytics*, there are numerous off-the-shelf solutions available (which often rely on cookies internally). [Google Analytics](https://www.google.com/analytics/) (proprietary) and [Piwik](http://piwik.org/) (OSS) are two well known examples of such software. For further advice on picking the best tool for your needs, please head over to [SoftwareRecs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).
3. This is typically an issue within the European Union. Again, there are numerous options readily available. For a list see [here](https://www.cookiechoices.org/).

Comment: First time I am going to use cookies, might be I will ask some stupid questions. I am bit unclear what to enter in the cookie_name and cookie_value, I got something

Comment: User identification: Once a user visits a webpage, using cookies, that user can be remembered. And later on, depending upon the search/visit pattern of the user, content which the user likely to be visited are served. A good example of this is 'Retargetting'. A concept used in online marketing, where depending upon the user's choice of content, advertisements of relevant product, which the user may buy, are served.

Comment: Tracking / Analytics: Cookies are used to track the user. Which, in turn, is used to analyze and serve various kind of data of great value, like location, technologies (e.g. browser, OS) form where the user visited, how long (s)he stayed on various pages etc.

Comment: I want to know these information as it describes in "User Identification" and "Tracking". And how can I check the cookie details and how can I serve the content as per user need (search/visit).

Comment: Basically the *name* and *value* can be anything you want. The rest of your questions is too broad to answer - it depends a lot on the technology you are using on your sever. But feel free to open a new question regarding this. Just be sure to make it specific (by giving the exact details of your environment and the problem you want to solve).

Comment: Sure I will open a new question, but what exactly you need, I mean as you mentioned technology on server. Can I know how can I check the cookies  reports.

Comment: Ok, is there anything else you need for *this* question to be answered to your satisfaction? Otherwise consider accepting the answer, so the question becomes archived and does not show up as unanswered anymore. For your other issues: Please make sure to read the FAQ on [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) - I am especially missing the *search/research* part on your side. I guess investing time into this would finally allow *you* to narrow down your problems so that we can actually provide good answers (and not blurry ones).

Comment: I really appreciate your efforts. Now I will read the FAQ first and then will ask the question here...

Comment: Then please either vote to delete this question (if you feel it is embarrassing...) or accept my answer (little gray hook next to it). Otherwise this will be orphaned and stay open forever.